# invalid master URI

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using the intel euclid vision system for my research, which has ros running on it by default on booting and it has a web interface. By mistake, i changed the ROS_MASTER_URI on the web interface and after a reboot, nothing is running. When I ssh into the device and run roscore by myself, I see the following error:

**invalid master URI: http://http://localhost:11311:11311/
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file**

Clearly the ROS_MASTER_URI is wrong but I dont know where to change it again because putting the correct one in the bashrc also doesnt allow roscore to run by default on booting. Is there any place, other than the bashrc where the ROS_MASTER_URI can be set? Please me help with this issue!
Since the ROS_MASTER_URI is set wrong, I am unable to reacess the web interface aswell!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264240/invalid-master-uri/) by [SubMarIN](https://answers.ros.org/users/30591/submarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could modify the ROS_MASTER_URI from $sudo vi /etc/hosts
This could be useful: https://github.com/mktk1117/six_wheel_robot/wiki/Communication-between-Raspberry-Pi-and-PC-(ROS)

---

Originally posted by [Grover1](https://answers.ros.org/users/30831/grover1/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0